# How to annotate Django query with days calculation?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

How do you annotate a Django query of a table with the calculation of days since the record was created?

I want to order a table based on a combined metric of priority multiplied by days since the record was created.

To get the days annotation, I'm trying to do:

```
qs = qs.annotate(days=(ExtractDay(Now()-F('created_datetime'))))
```

However, this is throwing the error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function pg_catalog.timezone(unknown, interval) does not exist
LINE 1: ...EMENT_TIMESTAMP() - "myapp_mymodel"."created_timestamp") AT TIME ZO...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've tried the similar [`Extract()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/database-functions/#extract) function, but it also produces a similar error.

What am I doing wrong?

Ostensibly, I just need to do the Django equivalent of `EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW() - created_timestamp)`, but Django's `Extract(..., 'days')` and `ExtractDay()` functions don't appear to actually match the PostgreSQL equivalents.

It looks like both the value returned by Django's `Now()` and my timestamp field are timezone-aware timestamps, so why is the database complaining about incompatible types?

My database backend is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query needs to specify what type the output of `Now() - F('created_datetime')` will be, since both are datetimes then Django assumes the output to also be a datetime (False here but works normally in other cases), hence you should use [`ExpressionWrapper` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) and provide an `output_field`:

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper

qs = qs.annotate(days=(ExtractDay(ExpressionWrapper(Now() - F('created_datetime'), output_field=DurationField()))))
```